# My window store and windows apps wont start and if I open a file regarding it, it shows "the signature is in valid"

Tags: windows, laptop

this all happened when I messed with the permissions of the windows apps folder and resetted my pc once, but it didn't fix my problem. I have tried multiple powershell commands but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

> I messed with the permissions of the windows apps folder and reset my
> pc once, but it didn't fix my problem.

Make a new, test Windows User Profile (Account).  Log into the new Windows Profile and test Store and other Apps and see if they are working.

A regular Windows 10 reset as you describe does not delete the existing User Account and I think your changes may have damaged the User Account.

This is why Reset did not fix the issue and the only practical fix is to back up the documents and email in your user profile, make a new temporary Admin Account, use the new Admin Account to delete the profile and make a new user profile.

If a new profile does not work, do a Windows 10 Repair Install. Use the Microsoft Media Creation link, use the second link down, run in place and use the option to Keep Everything.

That should work, but if not, back everything up and reinstall Windows fresh.

Instructions for the Windows 10 Repair Install

> Go to the Media Creation Link:
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to
> proceed, according to the severity of the error.
>
> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.

Comment: I created a new account but still the windows apps wont open in that account too.

Comment: I added information on how to do a Windows 10 Repair. I also noted that if the Repair does not work, you may need to backup and reinstall Windows.

Comment: oh thank you, i will try it and update you

Answer (score 0):

You need to restore the original permissions on the `WindowsApps` folder.
This folder is one of the most important and heavily protected folders in Windows 10.
It contains all the Windows UWP apps, to which Microsoft zealously guards the access.

To reset the permissions, run in an elevated Command Prompt (cmd) the following
command :

```
icacls "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /q /c /t /reset
```

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work, it shows 
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 15750 files
everything is on access denied

Comment: Try to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).